# Boost asynchronous timer still blocks the main thread

Tags: c++, boost, timer

I'm trying to use a boost timer to do some operations asynchronously:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
t.async_wait(timer_func);
io.run();
```

The problem is that io.run() is a blocking call. I would like to have an asynchronous timer that doesn't block the main thread, and then calls the callback on the main thread. Is this possible with boost?

Comment: Callbacks are executed on the thread that calls `io_sercice::run()` or `io_service::poll()`

Answer (score 1):

The `io_service::poll` doesn't block. You'll have though to implement some looping logic around it.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: On your main loop <code>while(_not_stopped) { io.poll(); } </code>